# What hibernate / jpa annotation is required

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create a new User(entity1) - it has reference to a Group (entity2) via a link table Member (entity3)

A user has a Set of groups as a class variable.

When i create my user object i want to say this user will be a member of group n (there are pre defined users that are linked to by id (1,2,3,4,5,6...) each group has some associated data in the table.

Whenever I create my user object as follows;

```
User user = new User();
user.setActive(1);
user.setCrby("me");
user.setUsername("username");
user.setCrdate("2016-06-20 12:42:53.610");
user.setCrwsref("...");
user.setModby("...");
user.setModdate("2016-06-20 12:42:53.610");
user.setModswref("..");
user.setBackground("Y");
user.setPassword("password");
user.setFullName("me");

Group group = new Group();
group.setId(1);

Group group2 = new Group();
group2.setId(2);

Set<Group> sets = new HashSet<Group>();
sets.add(group);
sets.add(group2);

user.setGroups(sets);

userDao.addUser(user);
```

I keep getting errors telling me that certain columns cannot be null. What I actually want to happen here is not to be doing an insert in to the group table but associating a user to a line in the group table. Is there a particular way I can prevent the columns in the group table being modified? I think I need to modify the mappings between the link table - this is how much pojos link right now

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "zmember", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "username")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id")})
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);
```

Member link table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "sgpid")
    private int sgpid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String memberUsername;
```

Group

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
```

What is happening is there is no association to the link Member table so ideally should User have a set of member objects rather than a set of groups?

Thanks - this was quite hard to explain so sorry if it is hard to understand

Comment: If you were Hibernate, how would you try to map the string `username` in `User` and the integer `id` in `Group`? Note that `Member` isn't related to both in any case - at least not from Hibernate's point of view. You'd probably want `User` to have a set of `Member` (and those have a back reference to `User` and are the owners of the relation) and `Member` has a `ManyToOne` relation to a `Group`.

Comment: "Member" has no relation with any other object so is not a "link table"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship from User to Group is essentially ManyToMany. You could model this is using the `@ManyToMany` annotation however one drawback with this approach is you cannot save additional information about the group in the join table such as 'date_joined'.

See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#ManyToMany

Using this approach you would not need the Join entity Member and the relationship on User would look like:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "zmember", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);
```

The alternative to using @ManyToMany is to use a Join entity Member(ship) as you have done. This would allow you to save additional data about the relationship (by defining additional field mappings in the Join entity).

In this case the mappings would look like:

User:

```
public class User{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Membership> memberships = new HashSet<Membership>(0);

    //if required, you can 'hide' the join entity from client code by    
    //encapsulating add remove operations etc.

    public void addToGroup(Group group){
        Membership membershup = new Membership();
        membership.setUser(this);
        membership.setGroup(group);
        memberships.add(membership);
    )

    public Set<Groupp> getGroups(){
        //iterate memberships and build collection of groups
    }
}
```

Membership:

```
public class Membership{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Member member;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;
}
```

Group:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     private Set<Membership> memberships = new HashSet<Membership>(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case for the `@ManyToMany` annotation. See for example:

https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html